# Sidebar reopening animation on page navigation through navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

So in this JavaScript below I run addEventListener click on a button, if clicked it will add to the .sidebar active class.

```
const sidebarbtn = document.querySelector('#sidebar-btn');
const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');

sidebarbtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    sidebar.classList.toggle('active');
    localStorage.setItem('sidebarActive', sidebar.classList.contains('active'));
});


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const isSidebarActive = localStorage.getItem('sidebarActive') === 'true';
    if (isSidebarActive) {
        sidebar.classList.add('active');
    }
});
```

Everything is working. If I open the sidebar and redirect using navbar to another page it will stay opened. The thing I am asking is more esthetical rather than functional.

When I navigate with opened sidebar, it will firstly load closed because it is default then it will open. The same thing happens with dark/light mode using the localStorage. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Unless you use a Single Page App framework such as Vue, so when navigating between pages there's no visible refresh then you will be struggling to achieve what you want.

Alternatively you could try hooking into pre-page loaded event listeners and see if you can access localStorage at that point.

https://tilomitra.com/html-page-lifecycle-events/

Comment: Okay. Into single page app frameworks I am completely new. You suggested Vue. Is it easy to learn Vue or are there any easier frameworks?

Comment: Vue is a good start if you have pretty firm ground with javascript. Have a go following this tutorial -> https://medium.com/simplejs/get-start-with-vuejs-for-absolute-beginners-b658fd3399f5
If your struggling and want to dm me on ig feel free https://www.instagram.com/frontendistro/